# How to use UI.Text as a prefab in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, unity3d-gui

I've tried using this

```
Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

It successfully created objects, as seen in my hierarchy. But I cannot see the text on the screen, even though there is a text assigned to it. I can only see an empty game object on the screen.

These screenshots show the game on play, and the selected object is the object instantiated through the script.

[image]

[image]

When I drag the prefab, it does not show anything on the scene. This happens to all my prefabs. The following are its components:

[image]

Comment: Please show the structure of prefab (how it looks if you drag it on scene) and where text you need is located.

Comment: @mwilczynski done. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

In new `Unity3D UI` system, every `UI` (`Text`, `Button`, `Panel` etc.) component that will be renderer on screen must have a parent `Canvas` component.
You actually do use such approach in your project, where you have `Toolbar`, `List` etc. that have parent called `Canvas` and which I suppose has `Canvas` component attached.

What you need to do is to move instantiated `gameObject` to be child of other `gameObject` that holds `Canvas` component.
As there can be multiple components of `Canvas` type, I would suggest to add possibility to assign **root** for instantiated objects inside your `Script`.

### Script:

```
//Drag and drop this from inspector; make sure that dragged gameObject
//has Canvas component in it or above it (in parent)
public Transform EntriesRoot;

void Start()
{
    var entry = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    //Put parent to our EntriesRoot
    //EntriesRoot will be our new parent for entry in hierarchy
    entry.transform.SetParent(EntriesRoot)
}
```

Comment: SetParent is not supported in the latest version of Unity which is 5.3. Is there another way to instantiate this prefab as a child of the Canvas object?

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.3.1 and it's definitely supported. You should indeed use SetParent on transform component, my bad (edited already). The way that is deprecated now is `transform.parent = otherTransform` not `transform.SetParent(otherTransform)`. What is the exact error?

Comment: There is a convenience to set the parent transform as part of `Instantiate` as well.
`GameObject text = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity, EntriesRoot);`

Answer (score 2):

they need to be a child of a Canvas, that displays them.

```
 // find canvas
GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
// clone your prefab
GameObject text = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
// set canvas as parent to the text
text.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each instance, you might have to manually enable the guiTexture.

Comment: how do i do that? the method Instantiate returns an UnityEngine.Object. That class does not have a field "enabled".

Comment: I cant manipulate the object as a text because its type is not GUIText, rather it's Object. Casting doesnt work either

Comment: if the prefab is enabled the cloned copy will be enabled too.